# How to compile for the old ABI libstdc++?

Tags: gcc, cmake

My production environment is Centos 7 that is limited to:

- GLIBCXX_3.4.19
- CXXABI_1.3.7

On that envirnoment, whether I use gcc 4.8.5 or gcc 7.3.1 (devtoolset-7), it still uses the old ABI libstdc++.

---

My development environment is a **Centos 8 Stream** with the new **libstdc++11** and **gcc 8.4.1**:

- GLIBCXX_3.4.25
- CXXABI_1.3.11

Of course, running my app compiled on Centos 8 Stream, on Centos 7, I get the famous:

- version GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found
- version CXXABI_1.3.9' not found

#### **Question:**

From **Centos 8 Stream**, how can I tell CMake to use the **old ABI** so that it'll be compatible with Centos 7?

Conan has a `compiler.libcxx=libstdc++` option.

I do have `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)`, C++11 is supported by both gcc versions.

#### Tries

- `cmake -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 ..`

```
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI
```

- `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`

```
/usr/bin/ld: Dwarf Error: Invalid abstract instance DIE ref.
/tmp/ccXH3FbV.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `main':
<artificial>:(.text+0xbb5): undefined reference to `MyLib::getStateString[abi:cxx11]()'
<artificial>:(.text+0xbe0): undefined reference to `MyLib::getState2String[abi:cxx11]()'
<artificial>:(.text+0xeb8): undefined reference to `MyLib::MyLib(unsigned char, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
```